# Understanding this code

Tags: java, android, sd-card, uuid

Kind of need help understanding what this code actually outputs.  Does it out put a uuid to a file? 
I found it on http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

```
    public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
        if (sID == null) {  
            File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), INSTALLATION);
            try {
                if (!installation.exists())
                    writeInstallationFile(installation);
                sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return sID;
    }

    private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        f.readFully(bytes);
        f.close();
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private static void writeInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        out.write(id.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The code exactly how it is posted in my app.

```
package com.UUIID;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UUIDActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView text;
    private static final String TAG = "Installation";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d(TAG, "program started");
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfield);

    }

    class Installation {

        private String sID = null;
        private static final String INSTALLATION = "INSTALLATION";

        public synchronized String id(Context context) {
            if (sID == null) {
                File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(),
                        INSTALLATION);
                try {

                    if (!installation.exists())
                        writeInstallationFile(installation);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Inside of installation If statement");
                    sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            return sID;
        }

        private String readInstallationFile(File installation)
                throws IOException {
            RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
            f.readFully(bytes);
            Log.d(TAG, "Right before it calls f to close");
            f.close();
            return new String(bytes);
        }

        private void writeInstallationFile(File installation)
                throws IOException {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "Right before the file gets written out.");
            out.write(id.getBytes());
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so i understand the code writes the UUID to a file if it has never been created on phone.  I've searched through my phones SD card and i dont see any specific file that has a UUID in it.  However there is one folder that is unreadable, Is the UUID Private? from even the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public synchronized static String id(Context context)
```

returns a persistent UUID (generated by UUID.randomUUID()). In other words, it will return the same UUID every time. As @Alonso Domiguez answered, it's probably an installation ID, based on the naming. The goal is to give each instance of the application that uses this code a unique ID.

The trick here is

```
if (!installation.exists())
    writeInstallationFile(installation);
sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
```

The function:

```
writeInstallationFile(installation)
```

generates a random UUID, and writes that the UUID to a hard-coded file. However, it will only be called once; because after the first call, !installation.exists() will always be false (because the writing of the UUID creates that file).

Comment: Okay so i understand the code writes the UUID to a file if it has never been created on phone. I've searched through my phones SD card and i dont see any specific file that has a UUID in it. However there is one folder that is unreadable, Is the UUID Private? from even the user?

Comment: The file is created at the location that is in the folder context.getFilesDir(), with the name INSTALLATION (which is actually a (probably constant) variable somewhere in the code). If you want to see where this is, you could try inserting a Log statement with those two values - it's conceivable (although I don't know for sure) that files are hidden from the SD card explorer.

Comment: Okay so all i got it to do was to log when the program started, as from what i can tell the program does not go into any of the methods.

Comment: are you calling the id() method in your app somewhere? in other words, is there a reason for you to expect that this code should execute?

Comment: I've posted the code directly how it is displayed in my application.  All i did was copy and paste it from website and try to run it can you try pasting it in your IDE and running it?  BTW Thanks again for all help you've been giving me.

Comment: two things here: (1) when you declare "public synchronized String id...", it should be "public synchronized static String id(Context context)", and (2) you're never actually calling id(). Try adding into your onCreate a line like: "Installation.id(this);" and see what log you get.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view it returns the UUID of the installation, not "a UUID to a file" as such thing doesn't exist.

The UUID gets generated the first time you try to get that ID for the installation and stored inside a file so further calls using the same context will return that previous generated UUID.

Answer (score 1):

The code returns a random UUID, which is persisted to a file. If the UUID was already generated it reads it from the file, otherwise it creates it randomly and then saves it to the file